# In Sublime Text 2, how to select beginning and end of selected block?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

The [old docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection) for Sublime Text have this tantalizing note:

> Given a selected block of text, Ctrl+Shift+K will split it into two selections, one for each end.

That'd be quite handy, but it doesn't work in Sublime Text 2, at least not on my Mac. (Instead, the keystroke deletes the current line.)

I know it's easy enough to map any Sublime command to any keystroke, but I despite looking around I can't find the command for split-selected-block-into-start-and-end-selections.

So, what's the command for this? Or otherwise how can I do this?

Comment: Still nothing - this can probably be easily made as a package. I don't know any Python but I might try have a crack at it, because I'd really love this feature - imagine turning a section of text from inline to block by splitting the selection and hitting Enter. It'd also make editing arbitrary tags a hell of a lot faster, if combined with another plugin to hit, say, `shift+esc` to use only your *last* editing cursor.

Answer (score 3):

While I recognize this question is now over a year old, I think this is a highly desirable feature. I haven't created a package for this yet, but I did create a plugin that will do the trick. Create a Python file (suggested name: selections.py) in your `Sublime Text 2/Packages/User` directory, and copy in the following code.

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def split_selection_to_begin_end(view):
    new_sel = []
    for s in view.sel():
        if not s.empty():
            new_sel.append(sublime.Region(s.a))
            new_sel.append(sublime.Region(s.b))
        else:
            new_sel.append(s)

    view.sel().clear()
    for s in new_sel:
        view.sel().add(s)


class SplitSelectionToBeginEndCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        split_selection_to_begin_end(self.view)
```

I decided to set the keystroke for this to `Ctrl+Shift+;` since it's convenient and wasn't mapped to anything in any of the packages I have installed. Add this or something similar to your User/Default (OS).sublime-keymap file.

```js
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "split_selection_to_begin_end" }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

using **Ctrl+Shift+L**, or **Command+Shift+L** on OS X, for more details refer to this - [Multiple Selection with the Keyboard](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)

Comment: Hey thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. Command+Shift+L is for selecting each line in a multiline block. I'm looking for selecting the beginning and end of a block, as referenced in the old docs I liked to (but absent from the new docs you linked to).

Answer (score 1):

It seems this have been removed in ST2. Take a look at this gist to have the list of the shortcuts of ST2 : [Sublime Text 2 – Useful Shortcuts (Mac OS X)](https://gist.github.com/1207002)

Comment: Say it ain't so! If so, that would certainly explain why it's not mentioned anywhere... But I'm hoping it's still in there as a command, if not as a default key binding.

Comment: You can find the exhaustive list of ST commands in `Packages/Default/Default.sublime-commands`.

Comment: Hmm... that file doesn't look at all exhaustive to me -- and in any case doesn't have anything about the command I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a shortcut, but you can do CTRL+Left Click(mouse) at the beginning and end of a block.

Comment: And I just noticed that you can select (highlight) a block anything and start typing, it will add your text at the beginning and end of the selected text.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but for me selecting a block and then typing replaces the block with whatever you type (as desired).

Comment: And thanks for the note about Ctrl+Click to add more selections (it's Command+Click on OS X). That's definitely a great Sublime feature. But still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are right, my fault, it just works for special characters such as double quotes :(