# Sublime Text 2 - Is the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+K assigned twice or is there an error in the documentation?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am learning Sublime Text 2 at the moment and got a little bit confused about the documentation.

[Here it says](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection):

> Given a selected block of text, Ctrl+Shift+K will split it into two
>   selections, one for each end.

[But here it says otherwise](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) (At Build 2036):

> Ctrl+Shift+K will delete the current line (all platforms)

So is this a error in the documentation, or do I miss something? Because when I try this myself in a document, Ctrl+Shift+K will delete the selected text. And what would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563725/in-sublime-text-2-how-to-select-beginning-and-end-of-selected-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can make out from looking at many files in the sublime text directory, this seems to be an error in the documentation. It doesn't seem to have been updated. From what I can tell from the [change log](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), from Build 2036 (i.e. 3 March 2011 onwards), `Ctrl+Shift+K` has meant "Delete current line". This seems to be true even based upon the files I took a look at in the sublime text directory. Wherever there is `ctrl+shift+k`, it always points to `res://Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro`.

However, @oobug has written a nice plugin to add this feature. See his answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165470/3696619 for the code.